# Queue URL in native Video Player android to play in queue

Tags: android, android-video-player

i have array of video  URL and i want to click on play all button and all video is being queue to Android Native Video player and play sequentially one by one .

```
      Uri myUri =Uri.parse(Url);

      Intent intent = new
      Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
      intent.setDataAndType(myUri, "video/*"); 

      startActivity(intent);
```

I am using above code to Play one URL .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Media player doesn't support queuing(aka playlists). However, you can listen for completion events. This way you will notified when media player finishes playing previous video, then you can play your new video.

```
setOnCompletionListener(MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener listener)
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(/*...*/);
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() 
        {           
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
            {
                // Add next video here

            }           
        });
mp.start();
```